# VBA copy columns from source sheet to specific location on active sheet with some of the same headers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a machine that outputs data to my source file called "Exported Labbook". When I click on my formatting sheet called "Sheet1" which runs a number of VBA files it first clears all data except the headers in "Sheet1". I want it to then search the sheet "Exported Labbook" for the headers found in sheet "Sheet1" copy the column associated with that header and then go to "Sheet1" find the header with the same name and paste the information. Because "Sheet1" has a lot of other code going to it I need the data in the specific location. For instance in "Exported Labbook" and "Sheet1" column A will always be copied to column A with the header "Sample List" but the data that needs to go into column Q on "Sheet1" will some times be in column C, E, or Q on the "Exported Labbook" sheet but will have the same header in both sheets irrespective of column. Finally, I want it to leave the columns blank if no match is found.

I am not experienced in VBA however, I have tried to manipulate many many many codes related to this topic with some success but I am still short of my goal. Meaning that likely the answer is out there but I am not good enough at VBA to manipulate it properly. The code below has me close to my desired result, however, when the headers on "Exported Labbook" do not match in name to the headers in "Sheet1" it fails. Also, sorry if the code is not formatted to the desired style, I did my best being new to VBA and the forum. If it helps these are my column names in "Sheet1": "Sample List", "60Ni", "65Cu", "66Zn", "75As", "82Se", "111Cd", "205Tl", "208Pb"

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindandCopy()

Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
     Dim Rng As Range, c As Range
     Dim sCell As Range
     Dim rSize As Long
     Dim dest As Range
     Dim lDestRow As Long
     Dim i As Integer

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        i = 0
        Set Rng = Range([A1], [R1])
For Each c In Rng
        Set sCell = Sheets("Exported Labbook").Range("1:1").Find(What:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        rSize = Sheets("Exported Labbook").Range(sCell.Offset(1, 0), sCell.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
    If c.Offset(1, 0).Value <> "" Then
        Set dest = c.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
             If i = 0 Then
             lDestRow = dest.Row
             End If

             If dest.Row < lDestRow Then
             Set dest = Cells(lDestRow, dest.Column)
             End If

        Sheets("Exported Labbook").Range(sCell.Offset(1, 0), sCell.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        dest.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Else
        Range(sCell.Offset(1, 0), sCell.End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        Set dest = c.Offset(1, 0)

             If dest.Row < lDestRow Then
             Set dest = Cells(lDestRow, dest.Column)
             End If

        dest.Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

If headers on both sheets match it will do exactly what I want even if they are in a different order. If they do not for example if some are missing on sheet "Exported Labbook" I get the error Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. When this occurs debugging points to the line that starts rSize = Sheets. This problem really has me stumped. Thank you, everyone, for any help in advance. Oh also to be clear I am not married to this code if this is a bad way to approach this problem I am fine with trying something different.

Comment: To avoid the error, you need to first check that the find has produced a result, ie. `if not scell is nothing then ...`.

Comment: @SJR You have fixed my broken in 6 words thank you so so much.

Comment: Not sure how to close or give SJR the forum credit properly due but my question has been answered